# concurrent AP-STA mode in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wifi, ubuntu-20.04, access-point, networkmanager

I'm using a Jetson Xavier NX hardware with dual band network controller(Intel 8265). So as far as I know, concurrent AP-STA mode can be done.

I've seen some related tutorials([#1](https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Wifi_NetworkManager#WiFi_STA.2FAP_concurrency), [#2](https://docs.khadas.com/linux/vim4/wifi_apsta_mode.html)) on concurrent AP-STA mode, but just adding interface seems not enough.

I tried step-by-step as below:

```
nmcli radio wifi off
sudo iw phy phy0 interface add wlan1 type managed
```

At this moment, I can see that both Wi-Fi `wlan0` and `wlan1` are Off from GUI. from `nmcli device show`, both devices `wlan0` and `wlan1` are in 20 state (unavailable).

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
```

[image: Wi-Fi radio button off]

When I turn the Wi-Fi radio on, `wlan0` becomes 30 state (disconnected) and I can set `wlan0` as AP or STA as I want. However, `wlan1` remain 20 state and it shows no text at all on GUI as captured below.

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
```

[image: Wi-Fi radio button on]

Any way to solve the problem like changing the state of `wlan1`, or any other methods are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but found that the following order works

1. Setup and finish the connection for `wlan0`
2. Add `wlan1` interface (in my case, `sudo iw phy phy0 interface add wlan1 type managed`)
3. Setup and finish the connection for `wlan1`

But there is still a (crucial) problem that after adding `wlan1`, nearly 10 seconds needed to recognize for `wlan1` to connect to WiFi.